# How to avoid memory error in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

I am getting memory error while creating dataframe. I am reading zip file from s3 and writing the Byte data into dataframe but I am getting memory error. Could you please help me how to avoid this or what changes can I do in my code?

code-

```
list_table = []
for table in d:
    dict_table = OrderedDict()
    s_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("start_time--->>",s_time)
    print("tablename--->>", table)
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    key='raw/vs-1/load-1619/data' +'/'+ table
    obj = s3.Object('*******',key)
    n = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    gzipfile = BytesIO(n)
    gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipfile)
    content = gzipfile.read()
    #print(content)
    content_str = content.decode('utf-8')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in str(content_str).split('\n')])
    #print(df1)
    #count = os.popen('aws s3 cp s3://itx-agu-lake/raw/vs-1/load-1619/data/{0} - | wc -l'.format(table)).read()
    count = int(len(df1)) - 2
    del(df1)
    e_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("End_time---->>",e_time)
    
    print(count)
    dict_table['Table_Name'] = str(table)
    dict_table['Count'] = count
    list_table.append(dict_table)
```

I am getting memory error in below line-

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in str(content_str).split('\n')])
```

Error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ravi_sir.py", line 45, in <module>
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in str(content_str).split('\n')])
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 520, in __init__
    mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 93, in arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1650, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1739, in form_blocks
    object_blocks = _simple_blockify(items_dict["ObjectBlock"], np.object_)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1784, in _simple_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(tuples, dtype)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1830, in _stack_arrays
    stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to utilize the Pandas series string split method?

```py
# a sample string
content_str = 'a,b,c,d\nd,e,f,g\nh,i,j,k'

content_str = str(content_str).split('\n')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(content_str)
df1 = df1[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Posted here instead of the comments because it isn't pretty to post code there.

Comment: getting error in this line -  df1 = df1[0].str.split(',', expand=True)